# PHP $_GET['action']

Tags: php, get

I am trying to teach myself PHP and have been doing so for a couple weeks now. I'm currently trying to wrap my head around GET and POST methods, particularly GET. This is just some basic code I wrote:

```
<html>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Laugh">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Cry">
    </form>
</html>

<?php
    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : NULL;

    switch ($action) {
        case 'Laugh': 
            echo 'You laughed!';
            break;
        case 'Cry':
            echo 'You cried!';
            break;
    }
?>
```

Upon clicking the Submit buttons, the above code will display the case result respectively. This works for submit buttons. How would I obtain the same result if I were to use links instead of submit buttons? I'd like to be able to click on a link and have it take me to one of the switch cases. I have tried searching online, and I was unable to get any information on this.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: **Avoid** using the same names in your forms for it will bring confusion for when you needed it most

Comment: having the same name will result to an array datatype of your get variable. you can access it $_GET['action'][0] or $_GET['action'][1]

Comment: You need to use java script for that purpose

Comment: If user presses the link what you want to do output cry or laugh?

Comment: how about using radio button instead? that would make your life easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an anchor:

```
<a href="?action=Laugh">Please Laugh</a><br>
<a href="?action=Cry">Please Cry</a>
```

Your PHP code can be unchanged.

Comment: That addresses my question perfectly. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @DavidChen If I have `href="./?action=deliver&id=6945"` do I also need use the `deliver&id=6945` for inside the `$action = isset($_GET['action'])` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like values passed in a link you will want to use the $_GET method. The get method passes values using a URL. So say you wanted to get the values using a link it would look something like

```
<a id="link" href="./?action=Laughed">Link</a>
```

You would be able to get the value of action like

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
```

Of course you will want to clean this up because users will be able to pass their own values using the same URL as

```
 http://YourFile.php?action=WhateverIWant!
```

And if you require the POST method you can use javascript to have this done. In your javascript you can have

```
document.getElementById("link").addEventListener("click",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     document.getElementById("form-id-here").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string.

```
<form>
    <a href="a.com?id='1'" >Laugh</a>
    <a href="a.com?id='2'" >Cry</a>
</form>

<?php
    $action = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL;

    switch ($action) 
    {
        case '1': 
            echo 'You laughed!';
            break;
        case '2':
            echo 'You cried!';
            break;
        default: 
            echo 'No Resuke Match';
    }
?>
```